# MariaDB performance issue with "Where IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I got an issue with my SQL code. We developed an application which runs on MySQL, and there it runs fine. So I decided to give MariaDB a try and installed it on a dev machine.  On a certain query Stmt, i have a performance issue I do not understand. The query is the following:

```
 SELECT SAMPLES.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SAMPLES.SAMPLE_DATE) as TIMESTAMP,RAWS.VALUE, DATAKEYS.RAW_ID, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_VALUE, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID, KEYDEF.KEY_NAME, KEYDEF.LDD_ID 
FROM 
PDS.TABLE_SAMPLES SAMPLES 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PDS.TABLE_RAW_VALUES RAWS ON SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID = RAWS.SAMPLE_ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PDS.TABLE_SAMPLE_DATA_KEYS DATAKEYS ON(DATAKEYS.RAW_ID = RAWS.RAW_ID AND DATAKEYS.SAMPLE_ID = SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID) OR 
(DATAKEYS.RAW_ID = 0 AND DATAKEYS.SAMPLE_ID = SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID) 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PDS.TABLE_DATA_KEY_DEFINITION KEYDEF ON(DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID = KEYDEF.DATA_KEY_ID) 
WHERE 
SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID IN(1991331,1991637,1991941,2046105,2046411,2046717,2047023,2047635,2047941,2048247)
AND (SAMPLES.PARAMETER_ID = 9) 
GROUP BY DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID, RAWS.RAW_ID, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID 
ORDER BY SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID, DATAKEYS.RAW_ID;
```

As long as I got only ONE value in the "WHERE IN" condition, the query takes ~10ms to execute. That's about the same MySQL 5.6 took.
As soon as I add another value there, the query time raises to several minutes. In MySQL, it raises very slowly, the Query shown up tehre takes ~150ms on MySQL and about 140 seconds on the new MariaDB installation using exactly the same datasets.

I'm no SQL expert, can you give me some clues how to optimize the query to run as expected?

Comment: Is the samples.sample_id an indexed column?

Comment: Just a remark, `right outer join` makes no sense here if you are using `sample_id` in the `where` clause, better change all to `inner join`

Comment: What's the point of having `SAMPLES.*` in your select statement, you aren't grouping on any of them

Comment: yes, sample_id is indexed and unique

Comment: can you post an `explain` ? can help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `right outer join`s are being converted to inner joins by the `where` clause.  So, just use the proper `join` type (I'm not sure if this affects the optimization of the query, but it could):

```
SELECT SAMPLES.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SAMPLES.SAMPLE_DATE) as TIMESTAMP,RAWS.VALUE, DATAKEYS.RAW_ID, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_VALUE, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID, KEYDEF.KEY_NAME, KEYDEF.LDD_ID 
FROM PDS.TABLE_SAMPLES SAMPLES JOIN
     PDS.TABLE_RAW_VALUES RAWS
     ON SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID = RAWS.SAMPLE_ID JOIN
     PDS.TABLE_SAMPLE_DATA_KEYS DATAKEYS
     ON (DATAKEYS.RAW_ID = RAWS.RAW_ID AND DATAKEYS.SAMPLE_ID = SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID) OR 
        (DATAKEYS.RAW_ID = 0 AND DATAKEYS.SAMPLE_ID = SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID) JOIN
     PDS.TABLE_DATA_KEY_DEFINITION KEYDEF
     ON DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID = KEYDEF.DATA_KEY_ID)
WHERE SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID IN (1991331, 1991637, 1991941, 2046105, 2046411, 2046717, 2047023, 2047635, 2047941, 2048247) AND
      (SAMPLES.PARAMETER_ID = 9) 
GROUP BY DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID, RAWS.RAW_ID, DATAKEYS.DATA_KEY_ID 
ORDER BY SAMPLES.SAMPLE_ID, DATAKEYS.RAW_ID;
```

Next, the best index for this query -- regardless of the number of values in the `IN` is the composite index `PDS.TABLE_SAMPLES(PARAMETER_ID, SAMPLE_ID)`.  This handles the `WHERE` clause.

Because your query runs quickly under some circumstances, I assume the other tables have the appropriate indexes for the joins.

Comment: The indices where correct, PDS.TABLE_SAMPLES(PARAMETER_ID, SAMPLE_ID) is the primary key for this table. However, the wrong join types were the problem. When using an inner join, the problem disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operator 'IN' try using 'exists' and the use the subquery
instead of using sample_id's.